# url submitted to codeigniter controller gets decoded wrong

Tags: forms, codeigniter, url

I have a url that I want to save, so I have my jquery ajax post to a controller, and I can see that the post is
http://www.nailsupplies.us/products/ESSIE%252dMatte-About-You-0.5oz..html but when simply return $this->input->post('link');
I get
http://www.nailsupplies.us/products/ESSIE%2dMatte-About-You-0.5oz..html

at first I thought it might be some crazy XSS filter, but even setting the second parameter false doesn't affect this, and doing a $_POST doesn't either so what the heck is up with this issue?

**To reproduce**
You can test it yourself by going to [http://e-ønsker.dk](http://e-%C3%B8nsker.dk) and then click "Tilføj ønske" - if you then click the link-chain icon to the left, insert a URL and hit the "GEM" (save) button you will see both the ajax post and response, and the response is simply an output of $this->input->post()

And in case anynoe's wondering the language is danish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be experiencing double encoding. `%25` is being decoded as '%' which is correct. Try avoiding encoding the URL before the post.

You should get http://www.nailsupplies.us/products/ESSIE%2dMatte-About-You-0.5oz..html which will decode correctly to http://www.nailsupplies.us/products/ESSIE-Matte-About-You-0.5oz..html (`%2d`=`-`).

I can't help more without seeing your client side script. It's weird that it just encoded the first hyphen and not the following ones.

Comment: The weird thing is that the only url that works, as you can see by pressing is the http://www.nailsupplies.us/products/ESSIE%252dMatte-About-You-0.5oz..html. You can actually test it yourself in http://e-ønsker.dk and then click "Tilføj ønske" - if you then click the link-chain icon to the left, insert a URL and hit the "GEM" button you will see both the ajax post and response, and the response is simply an output of $this->input->post() thank you

Comment: Then it's the opposite problem. You need to encode the string in javascript ([encodeUri](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp)). You should encode and get .../products/ESSIE%2d252dMatte%2d... and that will then be decoded back again to .../products/ESSIE%252dMatte-.. .